# Get Average Value of Two+ HashMap using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have two `HashMap<String, Integer>` How can I get the average of the values?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = ...
map1.put("str1", 7);
map1.put("str2", 4);

HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = ...
map2.put("str1", 3);
map2.put("str2", 2);
```

The expected output is:

```
("str1") = 5;
("str2") = 3;
```

I am able to retrieve the sum of two maps as follows:

```
map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
```

But how can I retrieve the average of two maps using Java 8?

Update:

At the request of @ I am posting a larger portion of my code:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> map;

        HashMap<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        map = func1(); 
        map = func2();
        map = func3();

        for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, Double>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            HashMap<String, Double> mp = map.get(key);
            mp.forEach((k, v) -> map2.merge(k, v, (t, u) -> (t + u) / 2));

            for (Entry<String, Double> entry1 : mp.entrySet()) {

                StringfieldName = entry1.getKey();
                Double score= entry1.getValue();
                System.out.println(fieldName.toString() + " = " + score);

            }
        }
        return map2;
    }
```

Comment: If you already have the sum, what's stopping you from dividing it by 2 and getting the average?

Comment: I tried: `mp.forEach((k, v) -> map2.merge(k, v, Integer::sum) / 2)` but I cannot divide within this expression ("Void methods cannot return a value")

Comment: @kichik Depends on what he means by average. I assumed it was `sum / (map1.values().size() + map2.values().size())`

Comment: Also you need to be careful with integer division here if you're expecting a floating point result.

Comment: Somebody posted the right answer and removed it. This is the correct answer:  `mp.forEach((k, v) -> map2.merge(k, v, (t, u) -> (t + u) / 2));`

Comment: i was not sure about the solution for that i remove it

Comment: Your solutions seems right (it is off by a few integers sometimes for example it avg 280 / 3 = 95 instead of 93.3 but that's probably bec I'm using integer not double) but overall it is the right approach. I will remove my answer and accept yours.

Comment: @Little Kevin share some values of your map, with keys so we can understand more, or at least the way you fill your maps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you tried to do this :

```
map1.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, (t, u) -> (t + u) / 2));
```

Comment: For 3 HashMaps with the values: 100, 59 and 100 this produces a result of: `89.76225`. If I add `100 + 59 + 100 = 259` and **then** divide 259  by `3` it produces a result of `86.3` How can one modify this code so that it produces the same result?

Comment: so you are using 3 maps not 2 @LittleKevin right? can you show me your code please?

Comment: I actually have an array of maps in the format: `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> map;`  I am iterating through the outer  `Map ` and then averaging the  `Double ` values for all Strings with the same value (so there can be any numbers of maps). Do you want me to post this part of the code?

Comment: @LittleKevin i think you made something like `System.out.println((((100 + 59) / 2) + 100) / 2);` but this is not the same like this
`System.out.println((100 + 59 + 100) / 3);` you get my point ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not take advantage of Java 8 features altogether?

```
double avg = Stream.of(map1.values(), map2.values())
                   .map(set -> set.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue)))
                   .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Integer::doubleValue));
```

Comment: ... because you don't get the expected output?

Comment: @RobinTopper The OP is getting some rounding errors anyway (as stated in the comment above)

Comment: The idea was to merge averages by key into the first map. Yours is cool, but does something different.

Comment: Exactly @AlexPakka. That's what I meant

Comment: @AlexPakka gotcha, did not think it through when I posted the answer, thought the OP just wanted to calculate the average